# If $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}\to +\infty$ is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}=O(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}^{3/2})$ as $n\to+\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

Suppose that we have a sequence of positive numbers $\{a_{kn}\}, k,n\in\mathbb{N},$ and we know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}<+\infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}\to +\infty$.
Can we say that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}=O(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}^{3/2})$, i.e., is it correct that the order of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}^{3/2}$ is not less than the order of  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}$ (as $n\to +\infty$)?

Comment: What is the reason for believing $\frac{3}{2}$ is so special? If such claim were true, it would be true also by replacing $\frac{3}{2}$ with any other constant.

Comment: Any other constant that is bigger than 1.Of course, I just wanted to make it more specific.

Comment: Consider $a_{kn} = \frac{1}{k}$ for $k$ belonging to a set depending on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. Here is a counterexample.
$$
a_{k,n}=\begin{cases}n^{-\frac23},&\forall k \le n, \\
 0\ (\text{or }\frac1{k^2} \text{ if positivity is stricty observed}), &\forall k>n.
\end{cases}
$$
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k,n}\ge n^{\frac13}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k,n}^{3/2}<3$.